# How to enable JGroups logging in Infinispan

Tags: java, log4j, infinispan, jgroups, infinispan-8

I'm new to Infinispan. I am running a cluster with three asymmetric nodes with Infinispan Version(8.1.3).I wanted to track the requests in my log which is sending in between the nodes like Failure Detection requests or TCP Ping.But these requests are not printing in my infinispan log.I'm using log4j for logging and I dont know how to use JDK logger.

How to log/capture the requests of JGroups in Infinispan?

Also Can Someone help me on how to use JDKLogging in Infinispan?

**My log4j Configuration is :**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
    <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">
    <appender name="ROLL" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
        <param name="File" value="InfinispanLogs/infinispan.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c{1}] (%t) %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>




    <!-- ================ -->
    <!-- Limit categories -->
    <!-- ================ -->


    <category name="org.infinispan">
        <priority value="TRACE"/>
    </category>


    <category name="org.jgroups">
        <priority value="TRACE"/>
    </category>


    <!-- ======================= -->
    <!-- Setup the Root category -->

    <root>
        <priority value="TRACE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ROLL"/>
    </root>


</log4j:configuration>
```

**My JGroups configuration is :**

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">
    <UDP
         bind_port="${jgroups_port:9012}"
         ip_mcast="false"
         ip_ttl="4"
         tos="8"
         ucast_recv_buf_size="5M"
         ucast_send_buf_size="5M"
         mcast_recv_buf_size="5M"
         mcast_send_buf_size="5M"
         max_bundle_size="64K"
         max_bundle_timeout="30"
         enable_diagnostics="true"


         thread_naming_pattern="cl"


         timer_type="new3"
         timer.min_threads="2"
         timer.max_threads="4"
         timer.keep_alive_time="3000"
         timer.queue_max_size="500"


         thread_pool.enabled="true"
         thread_pool.min_threads="2"
         thread_pool.max_threads="8"
         thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
         thread_pool.queue_enabled="true"
         thread_pool.queue_max_size="10000"
         thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard"


         oob_thread_pool.enabled="true"
         oob_thread_pool.min_threads="5"
         oob_thread_pool.max_threads="10"
         oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
        oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
         oob_thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
         oob_thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard"/>
     <TCPPING initial_hosts="x.xx.xx.xxx[9011],x.xx.xx.xxx[9012],x.xx.xx.xxx[9013],x.xx.xx.xxx[9014]" port_range="0" />


    <MERGE3 max_interval="30000"
            min_interval="10000"/>
        <FD_SOCK/>
        <FD_ALL timeout="12000" interval="3000" timeout_check_interval="2000"/>
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"  />
    <BARRIER />
    <pbcast.NAKACK2 xmit_interval="500"
                    xmit_table_num_rows="100"
                    xmit_table_msgs_per_row="2000"
                    xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000"
                    max_msg_batch_size="500"
                    use_mcast_xmit="false"
                    discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
    <UNICAST3 xmit_interval="500"
              xmit_table_num_rows="100"
              xmit_table_msgs_per_row="2000"
              xmit_table_max_compaction_time="60000"
              conn_expiry_timeout="0"
              max_msg_batch_size="500"/>
    <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000" desired_avg_gossip="50000"
                   max_bytes="4M"/>
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="2000"
                view_bundling="true"/>
    <UFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <MFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="60K"  />
    <RSVP resend_interval="2000" timeout="10000"/>
   <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER />
    <!-- pbcast.FLUSH  /-->




</config>
```

Thanks in Advance,:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your appender needs TRACE instead of INFO:
`<param name="Threshold" value="TRACE"/>`

Comment: Sorry,The problem is with the old jars used for log4j.I do have another question,Can I Enable the logs only for the failure detection protocol and disable the logs for other protocols?

Comment: Yes, add loggers for org.jgroups.protocols.FD_ALL (or whichever failure detection protocol you want to be logged), and set the root logger (e.g. org.jgroups) to WARN